# template does not exist error when using solr with django haystack

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I am going through the haystack tutorial and have built the following directory structure for the search text file:

[image]

My search_indexes.py looks like the following:

```
class FoodIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='name')

    def get_model(self):
        return Food

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for model is updated."""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

When issue the command manage.py rebuild_index with the default backend from haystack it builds the index no problem.  When I issue the command connected to my solr backend, I get the following error:

> django.template.base.TemplateDoesNotExist:
>   search/indexes/nutrition/food_text.txt

How can I have the index successfully build with Solr like it does with the default backend?

Comment: should it not be looking for `nutrition/search/indexes/...` ?

Comment: @karthikr what do you mean?  I also tried moving food_text one directory up to the "indexes" directory, but same error.

Comment: No, sorry i meant it is not looking in the proper directory structure.. It is looking for `search/...` whereas it should look in `<package>/search/..` according to the directory structure you have shown in the question

Answer (score 2):

thanks @karthikr . I had the wrong directory structure.  It should be this:

[image]